# SQLAlchemy bulk insertion with null colums

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using [Session.bulk_insert_mappings()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_insert_mappings) to insert a number of entities, but I am having a problem when entities have `None` values.

The following bulk insert works fine, a single insert statement is used to insert all entities:

```
session.bulk_insert_mappings(Document, [
    dict(document_id=1, version=1, colA=True, colB='a'),
    dict(document_id=2, version=1, colA=True, colB='b'),
    dict(document_id=3, version=1, colA=True, colB='c')
])
```

But when one of the fields is `None`, SQLAlchemy will split up the insert in multiple statements:

```
session.bulk_insert_mappings(Document, [
    dict(document_id=1, version=1, colA=True, colB='a'),
    dict(document_id=2, version=1, colA=True, colB=None),
    dict(document_id=3, version=1, colA=True, colB='c')
])
```

Log:

```
INFO  [...] INSERT INTO api.documents (...) VALUES (...)
INFO  [...] {'colA': True, 'colB': 'a', 'version': 1, 'document_id': 1}
INFO  [...] INSERT INTO api.documents (...) VALUES (...)
INFO  [...] {'colA': True, 'version': 1, 'document_id': 2}
INFO  [...] INSERT INTO api.documents (...) VALUES (...)
INFO  [...] {'colA': True, 'colB': 'c', 'version': 1, 'document_id': 3}
```

I tried to replace `None` with [null()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.null), but then I am getting the following error "can't adapt type 'Null'":

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Null' [SQL: 'INSERT INTO api.documents (...) VALUES (...)'] [parameters: ({'colB': 'a', 'colA': True, 'version': 1, 'document_id': 1}, {'colB': <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Null object at 0x7f74679c0190>, 'colA': True, 'version': 1, 'document_id': 2}, {'colB': 'c', 'colA': True, 'version': 1, 'document_id': 3})]
```

**How can I make sure that a single insert statement is used even when some entities have `None` values?**

**Edit:** The mapping looks like this:

```
class Document(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'documents'

    document_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    version = Column(Integer, nullable=False, server_default='1')
    colA = Column(Boolean)
    colB = Column(Integer)
```

Comment: Have You tried to omit `colB`?

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup I just tried it, but it's the same result (3 insert statements are made).

Comment: Please show a `mapper` class (`Document`)

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup I updated my question.

Answer (score 4):

Following the SQLAlchemy docs http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/persistence_techniques.html:

> If we’d like to be able to use the Python value None and have this
>   also be persisted as NULL despite the presence of column defaults, we
>   can configure this for the ORM using a Core-level modifier
>   TypeEngine.evaluates_none(), which indicates a type where the ORM
>   should treat the value None the same as any other value and pass it
>   through, rather than omitting it as a “missing” value:

```
class MyObject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(
      String(50).evaluates_none(),  # indicate that None should always be passed
      nullable=True, server_default="default")

obj = MyObject(id=1, data=None)
session.add(obj)
session.commit()  # INSERT with the 'data' column explicitly set to None;
                  # the ORM uses this directly, bypassing all client-
                  # and server-side defaults, and the database will
                  # persist this as the NULL value
```

This probably solve Your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks for your answer. Your solution works but I'd like to avoid to change the model, because it's only for a migration script and I don't want that the normal application is affected. You can also set it globally with `TypeEngine.should_evaluate_none = True`, I'll have to test if that works in my case.